# what is the way to highlight the app icon in windows toolbar, similar to hangout and google chrome

Tags: google-chrome-app, progressive-web-apps

I need a way to highlight the icon of Desktop PWA in windows toolbar.
This feature is available in hangout when any new message arrives, the colour changes of hangout icon. Also google chrome is changing the colour of chrome icon in toolbar when it completes the downloading.

Tried below code, but chrome.app.window is going undefined

```
var appWindow = chrome.app.window.current();
appWindow.drawAttention();
```

(reference link:-[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389286/show-orange-windows-taskbar-icon-orange-when-a-chrome-packaged-app-gets-a-notifi))

Tried below code as well, but chrome.windows going undefined

```
chrome.windows.update(windowId, {drawAttention: true});
```

windowId will be -2 for current window

(reference link:-[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520255/how-do-i-make-a-chrome-extensions-window-blink-in-the-taskbar))

Did reading about manifest.json on:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest
and
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/

but did not find anything for highlighting the icon.

Need this feature for only chrome browser for version 68 and above

Comment: A "chrome app" is an entirely different technology so you can't use its API in a PWA.

Comment: Is there any way to highlight the icon in windows toolbar for PWA, need this to inform user about new update.